# iOS 4.2 camera and album problem

Tags: iphone, crash, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, ios-4.2

for some reason the same code I used to access the camera and photo album that used to work with previous iOS is not working. Whenever I open the camera application or the photo album the app crashes, and nothing appears on the crash log. I tested it for iOS 3.0 to 4.1 and it worked fine. Did this happen to anyone? is it a bug? It doesn't even get to the imagePickerController method, it crashes as  soon as it loads the camera or album.

The code I use is this:

```
#pragma mark Photo methods

- (void) getNewPhoto {
 UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 picker.delegate = self;
 picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
 [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}

- (void)loadPhotoFromLibrary {
 UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 picker.delegate = self;
 picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
 [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark ImagePickerController methods

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
 [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
 selectedImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what line it's crashing on? Set a breakpoint and step through. It looks completely fine to me (other than the formatting). Knowing precisely where it's crashing is key. As to iOS 4.2, I have code that is virtually identical to yours and it's working fine.

Comment: I can´t find the line, it crashes when it is presenting the uiimagepickercontroller, after it loads the camera or album it crashes

Comment: it happens when I test it on a device that has iOS 4.2. I've tested it on an iPhone and an iPod Touch, both with 4.2

Comment: Hi fede,

Are you using this code for iPhone or iPad?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hope ur issue got resolved, if not try this...

As far as i know, UIImagePickerController does not work for iPad...it cannot present any view controller, so try with UIPopoverController (for iPad)...i have used the same thing and it really worked well....